# TensorFlow Test Accuracy is 1, All SoftMax values 0.5

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, softmax

I have swapped in my own data in place of the MNIST data in the TensorFlow example, where I have 2d arrays as my model inputs (x), ie:

`[[379   1]
 [412   2]
...
 [205   1]
 [504   8]]`

and 1d outputs (y), ie:

`[20, 
 24,
...
 19,
 27]`

The following code produces 2d arrays `[0.5, 0.5]` for all training steps, and 1 for accuracy against test data (when test data is produced randomly).  Additionally, all weights and biases are zero.

```
for i in range(10):
  print 'iterator:'
  print i
  batch_ys = np.reshape(training_outputs, (300, 1))

  ## batch_xs.shape = (300, 2)
  batch_xs = training_inputs

  sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

  print 'softmax value'
  ## !! these are a all [ 0.5  0.5]  !!
  print(sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: batch_xs}))

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))

accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

test_outputs = np.random.rand(300, 1)

## the following prints 1
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: test_inputs, y_: test_outputs}))
```

Am I fundamentally missing something ?

Comment: I can only guess, since your snippet does not fully specify all vars ... but if tf behaves anything like numpy, then the problem is that the argmax for your outputs of shape (1, n) will be an array of 0's, since the largest index is the first (since it's the only one). However, the same is true for several entries of equal value - the argmax will here, too, select the first index ...

Comment: the issue isnt `argmax`, it's `softmax`, which produced a discrete classification density function, meaning that the sum of all features equals 1.  if there is just 1 feature, then it by definition of the CDF must be 1.  i was trying to predict the output number, instead of classify it